# Assign result of `log10(2)` to a constant

Tags: c, function, constants, return-value, return-type

I want to assign the result of `log10(2)` to a constant.

I did

```
const float f = log10(2);
```

And it tells that `Initializer element is not a constant expression`. I also defined a new function

```
const float Log10(float f) {
    return (const float)log10(f);
}
```

But the compiler is complaining(why wouldn't it? I'm also using `log10` function) that `Type qualifiers are ignored on function's return type`. Does that mean there are no functions which can return a constant? Then how can I do what I want to?

EDIT:

As some people have doubts, I included the `math.h` header file and linked it with `-lm`, but I'm using the `-pedantic` option in gcc, and it does not accept it.

Comment: Did you link with `-lm` (math library)?

Comment: If this is not a generic problem that you are trying to find an answer to, you can hard code the value of `log10(2)`. `const float f = 0.30102999566;`

Comment: Your workaround is not really meaningful. Please provide the error you get when you do not use the workaround.

Comment: `const float f = log10(2);` is perfectly valid. You must include `<math.h>` and link with the math library.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It might not be valid if done outside of function. Depends if the compiler will figure out it is a constant expression or not.

Comment: @RSahu This is indeed what an optimizing compiler does; just replaces the expression with a constant at compile time. For that reason, you do not even need to link libm if you use log10(<some constant>).

Comment: ***Where*** did you define `const float f`?  It will only work as a local variable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It is also not valid when using the `-pedantic` option.

Comment: @WeatherVane Its okay if its local.

Comment: @Garmekain that's what I wrote. You can't assign a value to a global variable with the return value from a function, whether or not it is `const`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. That did it. An answer saying why it is so would be very helpful.

Comment: @Garmekain it most certainly is valid with `-pedantic` (but not for globals -- which you shouldn't be needing anyway). For your function, you need to return `float` and assign the return to a `const` qualified variable.

Comment: @EugeneSh.- good catch on the global part -- I wouldn't even have thought about that possibility...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So I wonder if it will ever be valid for global... Compiler can and will in fact replace it with constant.

Comment: I don't know. I seems like a quirk. I suspect the fact that there is an intermediary function call will always prevent the assignment to the global -- even through the return itself will be a constant value. Looks like global type will discard the `const` qualifier and default to `type` alone. However, it does allow a global to return `const` qualified *pointer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() { 
    const float f = log10(2);
    printf("%f\n", f);
}
```

But this will not work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const float f = log10(2);

int main() { 
    printf("%f\n", f);
}
```

because you cannot initialise a global variable from a function return value.

Note too that the compiler warns about mixing `float` with `double`. Never use `float` unless there are very good reasons why you *cannot* use `double`.

Comment: What compiler flags did you use? I don't get any warnings/errors with `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @Garmekain I don't use gcc.

Comment: @Garmekain it was "warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'const float', possible loss of data" and I don't see how compiler flags which suppress that are useful.

Comment: I see other answers in this post better and more informative than this one, even thought you were the first one to come to the conclussion.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `f` is declared at global level.

Unlike C++, C does not permit runtime expressions to be used when initializing global variables. All expressions must be computable at compile time.

Therefore

```
const float f = log10(2);
```

is not a valid C, while

```
const float f = 0.30102999566;
```

is valid.

From [C Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization):

> When initializing an object of static or thread-local storage duration, every expression in the initializer must be a constant expression or string literal.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that if `f` is a global variable, in C you need a compile-time constant expression to initialize it, and compile-time constant expressions can't include function calls such as `log10()`.

If you can move the line

```
const float f = log10(2);
```

into `main` or some other function, it will work.

If you need it to be global, you can declare it as

```
float f;
```

and then early in `main()` set

```
f = log10(2);
```

but the disadvantages are (a) `f` can not be `const` and (b) moving the initialization into `main` is a nuisance.

You can do

```
const float f = 0.301029995663981;   /* log10(2) */
```

but the disadvantage is pretty obvious.

Or you can use C++, where the restrictions on compile-time expressions are considerably relaxed, and

```
const float f = log10(2);
```

would work, I believe.

Comment: I would suggest using `const float f = 0.301029995663981f;` to avoid any potential issues with double rounding (from decimal literal to `double`, from `double` to `float`). Granted, such issues are rare, but there is a non-zero chance of them occurring.

Comment: @njuffa Well, if someone is using `float`, they've already said they don't care about precision.  So I think the only remaining issue is that some (especially Windows) compilers might issue a warning, and in this case that's a good thing, since it'll remind the OP to reconsider this issue.

Comment: These days it is more likely that they have determined that the use of `float` computation is *sufficient* from an accuracy perspective, while they benefit from the increase in performance, but also aware that they can ill afford to lose any of the few bits provided by `float` :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit: By that logic, somebody using `char` has said they do not care about range, so overflow in their expressions is never a concern.